# Let $U$ be open. Let $K \subset U$ be compact. Prove there exists some compact set $D$ such that $K \subset int(D)$ and $D \subset U$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am able to prove this for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology. I was wondering if it was true for generalized topological spaces. My intuition tells me it's true for complete and totally bounded metric spaces (since these are the properties I used to prove it true for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean metric) and for finite sets with the trivial or discrete topologies (I did an example or two in my head...which is the stuff bad proofs are made of).

Comment: You need a locally compact (Hausdorff) space for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel wrote, you need a locally compact space for that. Local compactness is certainly necessary, as for $K=\{x\}$ and $x\in U$, your property implies that $x$ has a compact neighborhood $D$ contained in $U$. But it is also sufficient. If $K\subseteq U$, then each point $x\in K$ possesses an open neighborhood $U_x$ contained in a compact set $K_x\subseteq U$. Choosing a finite cover of $K$ by these open sets, indexed by $x_1,\dots,x_n$, the union $D=\bigcup_{i=1}^n K_{x_i}$ is compact, contained in $U$, and its interior contains $K$.

A similar question would be: Given a compact set $K$ in an open set $U$, does there exist an open neighborhood $V$ of $K$ such that $\overline V$ is compact and contained in $U$? This property is stronger than the one you asked about, and it can be proven true only when the space is additionally Hausdorff or regular.